# Carrierwave option to remove the root from json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, carrierwave

I have been using carrierwave as the upload plugin in my ruby on rails application and lately I updated the version from 0.5.8 to 0.10.0. The json value of the mount_uploader attribute  gives different results in these versions
eg:

```
in 0.5.8 (console)
startup_obj.profile_image => {"url"=>"/uploads/startup/21/profile_image.jpg", "thumb"=>{"url"=>"/uploads/startup/21/thumb_profile_image.jpg"}}

in 0.10.0
startup_obj.profile_image =>  {"profile_image"=>{"url"=>"/uploads/startup/21/profile_image.jpg", "thumb"=>{"url"=>"/uploads/startup/21/thumb_profile_image.jpg"}}}
```

How can I make it work like old way and keep the new version?

Comment: this is *open source*, and case like this you should fix own.

Comment: Why negative vote? didn't get it

Comment: @Зелёный But we can ask to someone if there's an option like a config value.why would someone invent the wheel again?

Comment: If no in documentation, so not at all.

Comment: @Зелёный Okay, still I dont think this is an update which majority who are using carrierwave can neglect. must have been affected the whole application if the application is driven by ajax and json data. Thanks  for your co-operation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `serializable_hash` method:

```
[13] pry(main)> product.image.serializable_hash
=> {"url"=>"/uploads/product/image/17/avatar.jpeg"}
```

Comment: I could use that from now onwards, but then again I have to change lotta places in my application..I added one patch and will add that as answer

Answer (score 3):

I added a monkeypatch to make my application works as normal and keep the new version of carrierwave. Not a permanent solution though,

```
module CarrierWave
  module Uploader
    module Serialization
      extend ActiveSupport::Concern
      def as_json(options=nil)
        serializable_hash
      end
    end
  end
end
```

add this in lib/some_file.rb